# Replacing values for multiple different elements each time I poll the server - htmx

Tags: python, django, htmx

I'm trying to poll the server once every 5 seconds and update 3 different values on the page, all in different locations. I've watched a few tutorials on htmx and oob swaps and I think I'm close to the solution but I just can't get it.

The results are coming through fine from the backend, they're just all going into the div with the id="udp", where I trigger the server poll from. I think this is what's causing me the problem but I'm not sure whether I need to move the hx-trigger to ensure id="ujp" and id="uep" both get updated or if I've missed something else?

result.html:

```
        <div>
          <div class="card-body" style="margin: 0 auto">
              <div id="udp" hx-get="{% url 'result' %}" hx-trigger="every 5s" hx-swap-oob="true" style="text-align: center;">
                  {% include 'partials/updated_results.html' %}
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body" style="margin: 0 auto">
              <div id="uep" hx-swap-oob="true" style="text-align: center;">
                  {% include 'partials/updated_results.html' %}
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body" style="margin: 0 auto">
              <div id="ujp" hx-swap-oob="true" style="text-align: center;">
                  {% include 'partials/updated_results.html' %}
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

updated_prices.html:

```
<div id="udp"
  hx-target="#udp"
  hx-swap="outerHTML">
    {% if add_result1 %}
    <p>{{ add_result1.result }}</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Retrieving results...</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>

<div id="uep"
  hx-target="#uep"
  hx-swap="outerHTML">
    {% if add_result2 %}
    <p>{{ add_result2.result }}</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Retrieving results...</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>

<div id="ujp"
  hx-target="#ujp"
  hx-swap="outerHTML">
    {% if add_result3 %}
    <p>{{ add_result3.result }}</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Retrieving results...</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide the `hx-swap-oob="true"` attribute in the response HTML. Furthermore since you are using outerHTML swapping method, you also have to include all the other attributes as well, otherwise the polling will stop after the first cycle. One of the divs in the response (here the first one) does not need a `hx-swap-oob="true"` attribute because it will be the normal swapped content.

```
<div id="udp"
  hx-target="#udp"
  hx-get="{% url 'result' %}" 
  hx-trigger="every 5s" 
  hx-swap="outerHTML"
  style="text-align: center;">
    {% if add_result1 %}
    <p>{{ add_result1.result }}</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Retrieving results...</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>

<div id="uep" hx-swap-oob="true">
    {% if add_result2 %}
    <p>{{ add_result2.result }}</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Retrieving results...</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>

<div id="ujp" hx-swap-oob="true">
    {% if add_result3 %}
    <p>{{ add_result3.result }}</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Retrieving results...</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```